# CMake & dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libLTO.dylib

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, llvm

I am compiling my project using LLVM on Mac OS X with CLion and CMake.

My CMake configure is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(PPAP)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
# add_compile_options(-v)

include_directories(
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m
    /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.1/include
    )

set(SOURCE_FILES src/parser.cpp src/convert.cpp src/ast.cpp)
set(LIBRARIES    
    /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/libpython3.6.dylib
    /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.9.1/lib/libLLVM.dylib
    )

add_executable(PPAP ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(PPAP ${LIBRARIES})
```

Then I compile it successfully, but when I run it, I got:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libLTO.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libLLVM.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just linking `libLLVM.dylib` is not enough. Using **llvm-config** instead of adding libraries manually is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not ideal, but adding the library directories to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable in the CLion Run/Debug Configurations made the errors go away for me.

I'm still interested in a CMake-only solution without having to resort to DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.